# Select for boolean type in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a flag "active" in mysql database for users, this column is boolean type. From admin account I want to create a select options to select True/False if user is activated or not.
So in my form for user's information editing/creating I have:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('active') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label>Is user active?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="active" id="active">
        @if (old('active') == $user->active)
            <option value="1" selected>True</option>
        @else
            <option value="0">False</option>
        @endif
    </select>
</div>
```

The problem is it's only displaying "True" no "false" option if user is activated by PHPMyAdmin parameter changing or "False" option if user i deactivated the same way as above. Please help to understand how to list all options (True/False) and select by default the option previously selected so edit should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your HTML to the following:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('active') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label>Is user active?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="active" id="active">
        <option value="1" @if (old('active') == 1) selected @endif>True</option>
        <option value="0" @if (old('active') == 0) selected @endif>False</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

You should check for the value that was selected before by the user. And then use that value to choose the value. However, in the answer, I am not setting the default value which you should take care of.

Comment: Hello :) Thank you, now storing data is working but the value previously selected is not displaying it's always "false" by default when I try to edit user info.

Comment: Ok i found solution, I've changed ` @if (old('active') == 1` to ` @if (old('active') == $user->active` and same with 0. and it's working, thank you :)

Comment: Also do you know how it's called and where can I found info about that statements syntax with `?` and `:` `{{ $errors->has('active') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">` I guess it's some kind of if statement but i can't  find any site with info about what `?` means and `:`. I don't know how it's called :/

Comment: it's called the ternary operator `?` check for the condition before it. and if its true, it return the value after it (the if statement). `:` returns the value after it if the condition is false. this is how it works `is this true ? yes : no`

Comment: @TharakaDilshan Thank you! Do you have any site where I can find usage, syntax, descriptions of that operators?

Comment: it's called "Ternary Operator" so give it a search on google

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('active') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label>Is user active?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="active" id="active">
            <option value="1" {{ old('active') ? 'selected' }}>True</option>
            <option value="0" {{ !old('active') ? 'selected' }}>False</option>
    </select>
</div>
```